# First time SQL query is taking More time from Spring Boot application

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have to fetch some records and then display in output. In my Spring Boot Application, I am using JPA Specification for creating Criteria and then calling `repo.findALL(Specification, Pageable )`, query generated by JPA is below:

```
Select * 
From "Table" 
Where "condition1" and "condition2" and condition"3"  
OrderBy column1 desc 
    offset 0 rows` fetch next 10 rows only
```

This query sometimes take more than 40 secs and rest of the time some 100ms. Although this issue is very rare (Once in 300-400 times)
This table have around 40000 rows and one of the column is having JSON DATA

Is there any way to detect why this query taking much time randomly. When I manually triggered this query in DB then only once it took around 35+ secs and later on every time it is hardly taking 200ms. Any tool/approach to detect this rarely happening issue

Comment: Rare and non-stable issue? Firstly check does this query is present in slow log, does 35+ sec is query execution time. In most cases this is data transferring/receiving/formatting, network or application, issue...

Comment: hi @Akina, thank you for replying .  Yes it is rare and non-stable issue. Yes query present in logs, and once or twice this query took 35+secs but later on hardly 100-200 ms. Any way to trace this

Comment: [The Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html). Look for it - it should be enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for 40000 rows that amount of time for execution seems insane.

Do check your indexed columns.

Secondly, as per your question, the query takes long time when executing first time and shorter times while executed there after.
Databases use query_cache in order to perform faster executions.
When you execute a query for the first time, database has to go into execution plans for retrieving your result but when executed there after the execution plan is already there. Hence, it takes shorter interval to execute after first execution or ways to optimize your  query.

You can check your query execution plan with

```
explain Select * from "Table" where "condition1" and "condition2" and condition"3"  orderBy column1 desc offset 0 rows
```

Explain is a keyword which shows the tentative query execution plan.
Hope this helps.:)